"How do I list a year where I "did nothing" due to grief in a German CV without leaving a gap?"
In Germany and Austria, it seems to be the case that nobody leaves gaps on their CV and to do so is not normally a risk worth taking. (Although I would personally consider leaving gaps - see https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/199723/161151 as well as higher and lower voted answers to the question for background.)
My university deleted my academic results from my degree transcript for the first half of 2014 due this being a "special period" for me, where my mother had been admitted to hospital and lost her tenancy as a result. That year a friend in my university halls residence also passed away at a young age, which preceded my taking a leave of absence through the second half of 2014 and through 2015. I didn't really do anything in 2014, and only started volunteering in 2015.
How could I describe 2014 and 2015 on my German-style CV? Ideally I would able to separate it from my studies, since for some employers (including at least a few good employers I reckon)  the length taken in ones studies would be one of the indicators of future performance.
I appreciate it if you state which country you have experience in for you answer; non-DACH countries are not going to have the same workplace culture as Germany (though I think I might still be able to learn lessons from countries neighboring/very near Germany as long as everybody is writing both start and end dates and not leaving gaps on their CVs there).
Edit: I have just received advice from an employee of a cafe affiliated with the jobcentre. One of his preferred versions of my CV reads:
BSc [main subject], [university] [grade] Regelzeit 4 Jahre-------------------01.2016-02.2020
[course description]
Praktikum: XXX-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------07.2017-09.2017
[internship description]
Sabbatical ([persönliche Gründe OR Trauerfall OR suizid-Trauerfall]; 2015: Ehrenamt, [organisation y])--01.2014-12.2015
BSc [main subject], [university]---------------------------------------------------------09.2013-12.2013
BSc [secondary subject], [university]------------------------------------------------09.2012-09.2013
For context, I did something similar to a world travel in 2023 and called that a sabbatical too, so I have two sabbaticals on my CV. The jobcentre employee thought this is a good word to use in both specific cases and that it is fine to use twice, since that is my life. If somebody knows the German word for "Intercalation" (as used in university administration) I might use that instead.
The jobcentre employee was not to be drawn on whether I should write "persönliche Gründe" or "Trauerfall". I can see from the answer/comments that "personal reasons" might be preferred in the Netherlands and Scandinavia. My (British) friend advised me that writing "Bereavement" instead of "Personal Reasons" might avoid coming across as defensive or wishy-washy, and he thought this would be the case regardless of audience. He thought to be transparent would be better. However, I am not sure if "Trauerfall" has the same effect in German as "Bereavement" does in English, eg in case Trauerfall is a more odd word or is more seldom used, particularly in professional contexts. I suppose a German-speaker could answer that.

That gap was 10 years ago. That's quite some time ago, to the point of being something you may want to think if it's worth including on the CV (specially if the job you are seeking now doesn't relate to what you were doing back then)

10 years ago, and during your studies? Leave it out. Start your CV with the end of your studies. "Master of Desaster, September 2013". Done. After 10 years in the workforce I couldn't care less about how long you studied and where you went to school. Leave it be.

I'm German. Don't use Trauerfall (Bereavement). To be blunt, if it looks like you need to take 2 years off if someone around you dies, you look unemployable. E.g. wrt your mum, you can phrase that positively: Took some time out to support my ill mother or something in that vein.

@jwsc Would it be weird if I put to the left of my photo "PERSÖNLICHE DATEN¶Geboren.... [Date/Town]¶Wohnort.... [Address] ¶Studiumabschluss.... BSc [Subject/2020/Grade/University]" Or is it a thing that Ausbildung needs to have its own section? (Because, I've several lines describing specific statistical/lab/field procedures picked up during my degree, with specific course modules/internship highlighted. Even if the subject/year/uni of the degree is at the start - whether next to my basic info or in its own tiny section - I may be minded to put all that technical stuff at the end of the CV.)

With a gap that is a decade old, it becomes relevant to see if you have done enough interesting things in that decade to let your CV start after the gap, in a way that leaving off the earlier part is perceived as you trying to be efficient with the reader's time, rather than that you try to hide something.
If you cannot leave the gap out in that way, then just mention it as taking a gap year or a sabbatical for personal reasons. In your CV, you don't have to add more details, but if you get asked about it, don't try to evade the question. Just be honest that some difficult life-events happened that year and you needed the time to get your life back in order.

+1 Good answer - the gap is essentially a decade ago while the OP was still a student or on their first job.

Not sure if I should add this to the original question, but to clarify, I've not been in graduate-level work since graduating in 2020. (From 2020 I worked in the healthcare sector due to the labour shortage during covid.) Therefore the employer will be looking first and foremost at my degree, degree transcript, and academic reference letter, not my employment experience since the degree. Not sure if that makes a difference for your answer, or if your answer says the same.

@novice, that is a reason for not being able to leave the gap out. I intended my answer to be useful not just for your specific situation, but more broadly also for others in similar but different situations.

@novice I take it this is related to your other question here? I think in general you need not get into details in the CV, do that on the interview in case the employer asks about it and only then. What is important as someone fresh out of school with no work experience in the profession you studied, is to give emphasis on what the studies contained and various projects or practice work you did during the studies.

@BartvanIngenSchenau, describing it as "for personal reasons" seems like a good idea/agrees with Lundin's advice not to go into details. Not sure I could describe gardening/tourguiding at a historical attraction in the 2nd year of the interruption as a sabbatical. I'm intrigued by your idea of describing the whole thing as a "Gap Year"~you think it'd be alright to describe it that way when the interruption was 2 years long? Maybe "Intercalation" (see postgraduateforum.com/forum/phd/advice/thread/interruption-of-study-selling-it-on-a-cv-and-what-to-do/26902) if German has an equivalent word.

@Lundin, I upvoted your answer in the other thread you linked to. I started a new question to answer how to describe the nature of the interruption/leave of absence/Intercalation/Gap Year on the advice of Heinzi (at the bottom of the comment chain for his answer: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/199715/161151), given he said he was unable to think of a good way to phrase it. I suppose my question at this stage has become "what word can I use instead of Studienunterbrechung" (eg Gap Year, Intercalation) & is the nonspecific "for personal reasons" acceptable specifically in Germany/Austria.

@novice If you had any job during that time do include it, even if just some part-time job you don't think is relevant for your future employer. General workplace experience is always a merit. There's the scenario when someone immediately goes to uni after finishing lower education and so when they graduate they might not have any workplace experience at all, meaning they'll be less self-sufficient initially. Which is why any job you had in the past is a merit, at least until the point when you have experience in the trade you graduated in.

I am becoming persuaded of using the word "Sabbatical" to describe the two-year interruption to my studies. Do you think I can do so in spite of having having been at University and studying for the first 6 months thereof, for which period the university deleted the grades from my transcript in what it describes as a "deletion of studies"? I suppose you could think of a "deletion of studies" as a retroactively applied "Leave of Absence/Interruption of Studies".
